# Using datediff in sql jdbc query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, datediff

I'm attempting to create a JDBC query with the following statement

```
String query = "SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableName +
            "where datediff(d,DATECOLUMN2,getdate()) <= 1";
st = conn1.createStatement();
rs = st.executeQuery(query);  //receiving error here
```

I am receiving the following error message

```
java.sql.SQLException: "d" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.
```

I'm sure the query isn't recognizing the datediff function for some reason I am not sure why since i was previously using HQL in the same application and retrieving the values.

In an attempt to use an alternative function I used

```
{fn TIMESTAMPADD( SQL_TSI_DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)}
```

but it also failed I later on found that this is only used for Derby Database's

Can someone assist me in using the proper sql function to compare a date with the current date using JDBC

Comment: It would help to know your database type and version :)

Comment: FWIW, the query you posted works fine in sql server (after properly closing the quotes). That suggest the problem is in some other part of the query that we cannot see. Or you are using a different database type ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableName "+
               "where datediff(day,DATECOLUMN2,getdate()) <= 1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that as well as 'dd' also in all caps didn't work

Comment: @MarquisBlount: Did you merely try replacing `d` with `dd` or `day`? I guess the real issue is the actual position of the double quote after `tablename`. I suspect you didn't leave a space at the end of the string and, as a result, the table name merged with `where`. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma before from. Based on the error messages you are running this against SQL server.

```
String query = "SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableName " 
              +" where datediff(d,DATECOLUMN2,getdate()) <= 1";
```

Comment: sorry that came from me editing the query and removing additional fields that were irrelevant good catch though

Answer (score 0):

The comma after the "d" should be a dot:

```
where datediff(d.DATECOLUMN2,getdate())
--------------- ^ dot here
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted snippet doesn't have a closing double quote between `tableName` and `+`, but I figure that is just a typo. However, in your real code, where precisely is the double quote? Is it directly after `tablename`, like this

```
String query = "SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableName" +
```

or after the space that follows `tablename`, like this

```
String query = "SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableName "+
```

It is very likely the former, because in that case the resulting query would look exactly the way as to cause the error you are getting. Take a look at this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1,DATECOLUMN2 FROM tableNamewhere datediff(d,DATECOLUMN2,getdate()) <= 1
```

You can see that `where` merges with the table name and `datediff` becomes an alias. What follows is interpreted as table hints. (You can specify table hints without WITH in older versions of SQL Server/older compatibility levels.) Consequently, SQL Server stumbles over `d`, as that is indeed an incorrect table hint.